# Does a non-owner user profile have rights to wipe an Android phone?

Tags: google, permissions, profiles

My work is pushing the use of Sophos Mobile Control (SMC) for MDM purposes so we can sync our email to our personal devices. I have a Nexus 5 with Android 6.0 (stock) and my intention is to create a separate non-owner user profile for work. My concern is that if I install Sophos Mobile Control on that profile it will have rights to wipe my phone if lost. It's a nice option if I had control over it but I don't like the idea of anyone else having the ability to do so even for work-security purposes.

Also I found this article regarding permissions required by SMC:
https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/116995.aspx

Will those permissions only be available to the profile the app is installed on? Or can it read my SMS messages on my owner non-work profile for example?

Thanks!